# On the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $X^4 + 1$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

My question can be stated very simply: why is the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $X^4 + 1$ *not* the field $\mathbb{Q}[e^{i\pi/4}].$

After all, if one defines $\alpha = e^{i\pi/4}$, then
$$
X^4+1=(X - \alpha)(X- \alpha^3)(X-\alpha^{-1})(X-\alpha^{-3})
$$

I figure that the answer to my question will entail showing that what I'm calling "$\mathbb{Q}[e^{i\pi/4}]$" is essentially nonsense/invalid/ill-defined, etc., but I can't provide the argument myself.

BTW, I know (from my textbook) that the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $X^4+1$ is $\mathbb{Q}[i,\sqrt{2}]$, but from this knowledge I'm not able to discern exactly where my reasoning above goes wrong.

---

Let me try to elaborate on my confusion here.

Suppose I treat $\alpha$ as an "opaque symbol".  All I know is that $\alpha^4 + 1 = 0$.  How do I determine that the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\alpha^2=i$ so that $i$ is in the field you have defined.

Also $(\alpha+\alpha^{-1})^2=i+2+\frac 1i=2$ so that $\sqrt 2$ is in the field you have defined.

So your field contains $\mathbb Q (\sqrt 2, i)$, and you can just as easily show the inclusion the other way by writing $\alpha = (1+i)\frac {\sqrt 2}2$.

In fact $\alpha$ is a primitive element for the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, i)$, which is known to exist (by the primitive element theorem).

Fields differently specified can be the same without this being immediately obvious.

Comment: Thank you.  The fact that $\alpha^2$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}$ is the clue that the degree cannot be 2.

Comment: @kjo That's not quite right, but the fact that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (x^4+1) has degree $4$ over $\mathbb Q$ will do it. To show degree higher than $2$ you have to show that $\alpha$ doesn't satisfy any quadratic equation with rational coefficients. The roots of $x^2+x+1=0$ are complex cube roots of $1$, and they do generate a quadratic extension.

Answer (score 3):

In fact there isn't a confusion, as we have that $\mathbb{Q}\left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\right) = \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$

The inclusion $\mathbb{Q}\left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\right) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$ is trivial, as $e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}} = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)$. On the other side we have that $i = \left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\right)^2 \in \mathbb{Q}\left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\right)$. From here trivially $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}\left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\right)$ and so we can conclude that $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}\left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\right)$

Comment: Thanks.  I think I may have worded my question badly.  What's throwing me off is the expectation that the degree of an extension of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ would be 2, while in this case, with $\alpha = e^{i \pi/4}$, the degree is in fact 4...

Comment: @kjo Note that you have two extensions of degree two. And indeed $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}(i)][\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}] = 2 \cdot 2 = 4$

Comment: @kjo To follow up on your second question we know that the degree of the extension is the degree of the minimal polynomial. So now we know that $\alpha$ is a root of $x^4 +1$. To prove that this is the minimal we need to prove that $x^4 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Can you prove this?